# angular cli generate component in library doesn't create scss file

Tags: angular-cli

I created a new library today by running the create project command first:

```
ng new situ-angular-components --createApplication=false --skipTests=true --prefix=situ --style=scss
```

Then I created the library:

```
ng g library situ-angular-components
```

I expected that when I run `ng g c footer` it would create the component without the test file and with a SCSS file, but it doesn't:

[image]

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Not sure why this was marked down....

Comment: I also face this issue. Did you find any solutions?

Comment: No, it is still an issue

Answer (score 1):

Open you `angular.json` and check the `schematics/angular:component` tree

It should be like this

```
   "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "prefix": "app"
        }
      },
```

Comment: Yeah, that was missing, so I ran `ng config schematics.@schematics/angular:component.styleext scss` which created the schematic, but it still gerenates a css file instead of an scss file when I run `ng g c anything`